# Not able to add HTTPS enabled webservice as Service reference in Visual Studio 2008. Error 403

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services

if in IIS specify "require a clients certificate" while adding a HTTPS enabled WebService as Service reference through Visual Studio 2008, the following exception occured:

**There was an error downloading "https://10.95.185.119/service1.asmx". The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: "https://10.95.185.119/service1.asmx". The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.**

In IE i can get WSDL in IE without any problem. If I remove "requirement of the certificate" - all ok!

This problem is repeated when application is  running.

help please!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a proxy between you and the server that requires authentication (windows based I guess).  IE will have authenticated in a previous session which is why you're able to see the endpoint.

Visual Studio however, will not have authenticated against this proxy and this is why you're seeing the 403.

Comment: Can you open fiddler and see what the response is and where it is coming from?

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I used a "Add Web Reference" instead "Add Service Reference" of 2, and it worked!